# Display brightness control not working in 17.10

Tags: drivers, brightness, 17.10

I just upgraded to ubuntu 17.10 and now display brightness controls are not working, and i am not able to change display brightness at all. But it was working perfectly in 17.04

I also tried this method, but still not working.
When I saw system details, it shows unknown graphics.

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

What can I do now?

Answer (score 7):

1. Open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Edit the `/etc/default/grub` file by running:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/default/grub
   ```
3. Change the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` line to:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=Linux"
   ```
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit
6. Update GRUB by running:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
7. Reboot

Comment: You should never [use normal `sudo` to start graphical applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/270006/why-should-users-never-use-normal-sudo-to-start-graphical-applications), use `nano` or `sudo -H gedit` instead.

Comment: Thanks it works..;) old approach like 16.04 is not working for me but you made it!

Comment: …or `xhost +si:localuser:root`

Comment: Didn't work for me.

Comment: Perfect - simple and clear instructions, worked for me