# The brightness of laptop screen cannot be adjusted with either the buttons or the slider. Edit

Tags: nvidia, 17.10, brightness, settings, backlight

I have **Ubuntu 17.10** installed on a **MSI GT72VR** laptop with a single **nVidia GT1060** graphics card, grub2 as a bootand **Unity** as a desktop. I can't change the brightness in any way.  **Bright always is 100%**. I have tried the following options that have not worked.

**THINGS THAT HAVE NOT WORKED** [UPDATED OUTPUTS AT 30TH APRIL Of 2018]

- <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Bright Up</kbd> or <kbd>Bright Down</kbd> buttons shows icon inline at screen, but brigthnes can't change.
- Brightness slider at top bar doesn't work.
- GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splashacpi_backlight=vendor"
- GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splashacpi_backlight=native"
- GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splashacpi_backlight=video"
- GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splashacpi_backlight=none"
- Utility xbacklight shows "No outputs have backlight property"
- Using nouveau X.Org display driver from software update
- NVIDIA binary driver version 396
- NVIDIA binary driver version 390
- Changing file brigtness on /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/ and doesn't work
- Using latest Kernel upstream mainline version v4.15.7 (February 28)
- Live USB Ubuntu
- Using a file on /etc/X11/xorg.conf with Section "Device" ...
- Log session as "Ubuntu on XOrg" and disable Wayland

---

This is the output of **journalctl -b | grep -i nvidia** (thanks @WinEunuuchs2Unix)

```
mar 06 17:37:57 portatil kernel: nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
mar 06 17:37:57 portatil kernel: nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
mar 06 17:37:57 portatil kernel: nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
mar 06 17:37:57 portatil kernel: nvidia-nvlink: Nvlink Core is being initialized, major device number 244
mar 06 17:37:57 portatil kernel: nvidia 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
mar 06 17:37:57 portatil kernel: NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  390.25  Wed Jan 24 20:02:43 PST 2018 (using threaded interrupts)
mar 06 17:37:57 portatil kernel: nvidia-modeset: Loading NVIDIA Kernel Mode Setting Driver for UNIX platforms  390.25  Wed Jan 24 19:29:37 PST 2018
mar 06 17:37:57 portatil kernel: [drm] [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Loading driver
mar 06 17:37:57 portatil kernel: [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20160202 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
mar 06 17:37:57 portatil kernel: nvidia-uvm: Loaded the UVM driver in 8 mode, major device number 242
mar 06 17:37:59 portatil kernel: input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input16
mar 06 17:37:59 portatil kernel: input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input17
mar 06 17:37:59 portatil systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA Persistence Daemon...
mar 06 17:37:59 portatil nvidia-persistenced[896]: Verbose syslog connection opened
mar 06 17:37:59 portatil nvidia-persistenced[896]: Now running with user ID 122 and group ID 129
mar 06 17:37:59 portatil nvidia-persistenced[896]: Started (896)
mar 06 17:37:59 portatil nvidia-persistenced[896]: device 0000:01:00.0 - registered
mar 06 17:37:59 portatil systemd[1]: Started NVIDIA Persistence Daemon.
mar 06 17:37:59 portatil nvidia-persistenced[896]: Local RPC service initialized
mar 06 17:37:59 portatil nvidia-persistenced[896]: Received signal 15
mar 06 17:37:59 portatil systemd[1]: Stopping NVIDIA Persistence Daemon...
mar 06 17:37:59 portatil nvidia-persistenced[896]: Socket closed.
mar 06 17:37:59 portatil nvidia-persistenced[896]: PID file unlocked.
mar 06 17:37:59 portatil nvidia-persistenced[896]: PID file closed.
mar 06 17:37:59 portatil nvidia-persistenced[896]: The daemon no longer has permission to remove its runtime data directory /var/run/nvidia-persistenced
mar 06 17:37:59 portatil nvidia-persistenced[896]: Shutdown (896)
mar 06 17:37:59 portatil systemd[1]: Stopped NVIDIA Persistence Daemon.
mar 06 17:37:59 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (II) Module glx: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
mar 06 17:37:59 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (II) NVIDIA GLX Module  390.25  Wed Jan 24 19:23:51 PST 2018
mar 06 17:37:59 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
mar 06 17:37:59 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (II) Loading /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/nvidia_drv.so
mar 06 17:37:59 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
mar 06 17:37:59 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  390.25  Wed Jan 24 18:57:05 PST 2018
mar 06 17:37:59 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
mar 06 17:37:59 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (II) NVIDIA(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
mar 06 17:37:59 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (==) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (==) framebuffer bpp 32
mar 06 17:37:59 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
mar 06 17:37:59 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
mar 06 17:37:59 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
mar 06 17:37:59 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (**) NVIDIA(0): Option "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
mar 06 17:37:59 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
mar 06 17:37:59 portatil systemd[1]: Starting NVIDIA Persistence Daemon...
mar 06 17:37:59 portatil nvidia-persistenced[1036]: Verbose syslog connection opened
mar 06 17:37:59 portatil systemd[1]: Started NVIDIA Persistence Daemon.
mar 06 17:37:59 portatil nvidia-persistenced[1036]: Now running with user ID 122 and group ID 129
mar 06 17:37:59 portatil nvidia-persistenced[1036]: Started (1036)
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil nvidia-persistenced[1036]: device 0000:01:00.0 - registered
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil nvidia-persistenced[1036]: Local RPC service initialized
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil kernel: nvidia-modeset: Allocated GPU:0 (GPU-3d37c8bb-5a07-7825-b4bc-3a57452f2b5a) @ PCI:0000:01:00.0
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on GPU-0 at PCI:1:0:0
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-0
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-1 (boot)
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-2
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-3
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-4
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-5
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU GeForce GTX 1060 (GP106-B) at PCI:1:0:0 (GPU-0)
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 6291456 kBytes
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 86.06.1f.00.05
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CMN (DFP-1): connected
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CMN (DFP-1): Internal DisplayPort
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CMN (DFP-1): 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal DisplayPort
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal TMDS
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal DisplayPort
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: disconnected
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: Internal TMDS
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (==) NVIDIA(0):
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (==) NVIDIA(0): No modes were requested; the default mode "nvidia-auto-select"
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (==) NVIDIA(0):     will be used as the requested mode.
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (==) NVIDIA(0):
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (II) NVIDIA(0): Validated MetaModes:
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (II) NVIDIA(0):     "DFP-1:nvidia-auto-select"
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (II) NVIDIA(0): Virtual screen size determined to be 1920 x 1080
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(0): DPI set to (128, 130); computed from "UseEdidDpi" X config
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(0):     option
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (II) NVIDIA: Using 24576.00 MB of virtual memory for indirect memory
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (II) NVIDIA:     access.
mar 06 17:38:00 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (II) NVIDIA(0): Setting mode "DFP-1:nvidia-auto-select"
mar 06 17:38:01 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (==) NVIDIA(0): Disabling shared memory pixmaps
mar 06 17:38:01 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (==) NVIDIA(0): Backing store enabled
mar 06 17:38:01 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (==) NVIDIA(0): Silken mouse enabled
mar 06 17:38:01 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (==) NVIDIA(0): DPMS enabled
mar 06 17:38:01 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2] Setup complete
mar 06 17:38:01 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (II) NVIDIA(0): [DRI2]   VDPAU driver: nvidia
mar 06 17:38:01 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 (/dev/input/event15)
mar 06 17:38:01 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (II) config/udev: Adding input device HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 (/dev/input/event16)
mar 06 17:38:01 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CMN (DFP-1): connected
mar 06 17:38:01 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CMN (DFP-1): Internal DisplayPort
mar 06 17:38:01 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CMN (DFP-1): 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
mar 06 17:38:01 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
mar 06 17:38:02 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
mar 06 17:38:02 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
mar 06 17:38:02 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
mar 06 17:38:02 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
mar 06 17:38:02 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CMN (DFP-1): connected
mar 06 17:38:02 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CMN (DFP-1): Internal DisplayPort
mar 06 17:38:02 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CMN (DFP-1): 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
mar 06 17:38:02 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
mar 06 17:38:02 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
mar 06 17:38:02 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal DisplayPort
mar 06 17:38:02 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
mar 06 17:38:02 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
mar 06 17:38:02 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
mar 06 17:38:02 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal TMDS
mar 06 17:38:02 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
mar 06 17:38:02 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
mar 06 17:38:02 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
mar 06 17:38:02 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal DisplayPort
mar 06 17:38:02 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
mar 06 17:38:02 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
mar 06 17:38:02 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: disconnected
mar 06 17:38:02 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: Internal TMDS
mar 06 17:38:02 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
mar 06 17:38:02 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
mar 06 17:38:05 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
mar 06 17:38:05 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
mar 06 17:38:05 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
mar 06 17:38:05 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
mar 06 17:38:05 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CMN (DFP-1): connected
mar 06 17:38:05 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CMN (DFP-1): Internal DisplayPort
mar 06 17:38:05 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): CMN (DFP-1): 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
mar 06 17:38:05 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
mar 06 17:38:05 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: disconnected
mar 06 17:38:05 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: Internal DisplayPort
mar 06 17:38:05 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-2: 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
mar 06 17:38:05 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
mar 06 17:38:05 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: disconnected
mar 06 17:38:05 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: Internal TMDS
mar 06 17:38:05 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-3: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
mar 06 17:38:05 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
mar 06 17:38:05 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: disconnected
mar 06 17:38:05 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: Internal DisplayPort
mar 06 17:38:05 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-4: 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
mar 06 17:38:05 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
mar 06 17:38:05 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: disconnected
mar 06 17:38:05 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: Internal TMDS
mar 06 17:38:05 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-5: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
mar 06 17:38:05 portatil /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[1026]: (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
mar 06 17:38:15 portatil kernel: Modules linked in: ccm rfcomm arc4 bnep nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi msi_wmi sparse_keymap intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm irqbypass crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel pcbc aesni_intel aes_x86_64 crypto_simd glue_helper cryptd intel_cstate intel_rapl_perf ath10k_pci ath10k_core snd_hda_codec_realtek ath snd_hda_codec_generic mac80211 serio_raw cfg80211 snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_seq_midi snd_hda_core snd_seq_midi_event snd_hwdep snd_rawmidi snd_pcm snd_seq input_leds joydev snd_seq_device snd_timer snd hci_uart btusb btrtl soundcore btbcm serdev btqca btintel bluetooth mei_me mei shpchp intel_pch_thermal ecdh_generic tpm_crb acpi_als intel_lpss_acpi wmi intel_lpss mac_hid kfifo_buf industrialio acpi_pad nvidia_uvm(POE) parport_pc
mar 06 17:38:15 portatil kernel:  ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic usbhid nvidia_drm(POE) nvidia_modeset(POE) drm_kms_helper syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt fb_sys_fops drm nvidia(POE) ahci ipmi_devintf alx sdhci_pci psmouse sdhci mdio libahci ipmi_msghandler video pinctrl_sunrisepoint i2c_hid pinctrl_intel hid
mar 08 20:28:03 portatil gnome-software[1468]: running get-installed with refine-flags=require-license,require-description,require-size,require-rating,require-version,require-history,require-setup-action,require-origin,require-provenance,require-icon,require-permissions,require-origin-hostname,require-runtime with failure-flags=use-events with timeout=60 on plugin=snap on apps user/*/*/shell-extension/ubuntu-appindicators_ubuntu.com/*,user/*/*/shell-extension/ubuntu-dock_ubuntu.com/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-universe/desktop/chromium-browser.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-universe/desktop/pgadmin3.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/vim.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/org.gnome.DejaDup.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/software-properties-gnome.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/libreoffice-math.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/gnome-session-properties.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/vino-preferences.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/transmission-gtk.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/system-config-printer.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/display-im6.q16.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/org.gnome.font-viewer.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/rhythmbox.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/gnome-user-share-properties.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/update-manager.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/evince.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/org.gnome.baobab.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/remmina.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/libreoffice-calc.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/libreoffice-startcenter.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/shotwell.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/inputmethod/table.xml/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/org.gnome.Screenshot.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/libreoffice-impress.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/seahorse.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/eog.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/org.gnome.FileRoller/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/org.gnome.DiskUtility.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/org.gnome.Calendar.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/org.gnome.gedit.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/libreoffice-draw.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/org.gnome.Software.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/nvidia-settings.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/usb-creator-gtk.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/ibus-setup.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/org.gnome.Logs.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/libreoffice-writer.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/org.gnome.PowerStats.desktop/*,system/package/ubuntu-artful-main/desktop/org.gnome.Totem.desktop/*,system/snap/Tienda de snaps/desktop/intellij-idea-ultimate/*,system/snap/Tienda de snaps/desktop/vlc/*,system/snap/Tienda de snaps/runtime/core/* took 8350ms
```

This is **ll /sys/class/backlight**

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 0 mar  8 20:32 ./
drwxr-xr-x 67 root root 0 mar  6 17:37 ../
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root 0 mar  6 17:37 acpi_video0 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0/backlight/acpi_video0/
```

This is **dmesg | grep -i vga**

```
[    0.181221] pci 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: setting as boot VGA device
[    0.181221] pci 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: VGA device added: decodes=io+mem,owns=io+mem,locks=none
[    0.181221] pci 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: bridge control possible
[    0.181221] vgaarb: loaded
[    0.989512] fb0: EFI VGA frame buffer device
[    1.340831] nvidia 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: changed VGA decodes: olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem
[    3.073586] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
```

This is **lspci | grep -i vga**

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 131
    Memory at de000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
```

This is **uname -a**

```
Linux portatil 4.13.0-36-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 16 20:07:48 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

This is **xrandr --verbose**

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (0x68) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 381mm x 214mm
    Identifier: 0x63
    Timestamp:  531186
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 0.45
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0 1 2 3
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff000dae471700000000
        101a0104a5261578028ad5ad4f43ad26
        0f505400000001010101010101010101
        0101010101016477804a713834406442
        6a007dd610000018000000fe004e3137
        334848452d4733320a20000000fe0043
        4d4e0a202020202020202020000000fe
        004e3137334848452d4733320a20005f
    dithering depth: auto 
        supported: auto, 6 bpc, 8 bpc
    dithering mode: auto 
        supported: auto, off, static 2x2, dynamic 2x2, temporal
    scaling mode: None 
        supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
    color vibrance: 150 
        range: (0, 200)
    vibrant hue: 90 
        range: (0, 180)
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
  1920x1080 (0x68) 305.640MHz -HSync -VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 2020 end 2086 total 2250 skew    0 clock 135.84KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1086 end 1096 total 1132           clock 120.00Hz
  1680x1050 (0x69) 313.895MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1816 end 2000 total 2320 skew    0 clock 135.30KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1128           clock 119.95Hz
  1400x1050 (0x6a) 260.857MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1400 start 1512 end 1664 total 1928 skew    0 clock 135.30KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1057 total 1128           clock 119.95Hz
  1280x1024 (0x6b) 232.251MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1384 end 1520 total 1760 skew    0 clock 131.96KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1027 end 1034 total 1100           clock 119.96Hz
  1280x960 (0x6c) 217.767MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1384 end 1520 total 1760 skew    0 clock 123.73KHz
        v: height  960 start  963 end  967 total 1032           clock 119.89Hz
  1152x864 (0x6d) 176.450MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1152 start 1248 end 1368 total 1584 skew    0 clock 111.40KHz
        v: height  864 start  867 end  871 total  929           clock 119.91Hz
  1024x768 (0x6e) 137.890MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1104 end 1208 total 1392 skew    0 clock  99.06KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  775 total  826           clock 119.93Hz
  800x600 (0x6f) 83.055MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  856 end  936 total 1072 skew    0 clock  77.48KHz
        v: height  600 start  603 end  607 total  646           clock 119.93Hz
  640x480 (0x70) 52.625MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   640 start  680 end  744 total  848 skew    0 clock  62.06KHz
        v: height  480 start  483 end  487 total  518           clock 119.80Hz
  720x400 (0x71) 48.878MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   720 start  760 end  832 total  944 skew    0 clock  51.78KHz
        v: height  400 start  403 end  413 total  432           clock 119.86Hz
  640x400 (0x72) 43.079MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   640 start  672 end  736 total  832 skew    0 clock  51.78KHz
        v: height  400 start  403 end  409 total  432           clock 119.86Hz
  640x350 (0x73) 37.734MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width   640 start  672 end  736 total  832 skew    0 clock  45.35KHz
        v: height  350 start  353 end  363 total  378           clock 119.98Hz
```

This is **lsmod | grep nvidia**
nvidia_uvm            757760  0
nvidia_drm             40960  2
nvidia_modeset       1093632  5 nvidia_drm
drm_kms_helper        167936  1 nvidia_drm
drm                   360448  5 nvidia_drm,drm_kms_helper
nvidia              14323712  326 nvidia_modeset,nvidia_uvm
ipmi_msghandler        45056  2 nvidia,ipmi_devintf

Thanks everybody

Comment: Can you include `journalctl -b | grep -i nvidia`?

Comment: WinEunuuchs2Unix you are on the main hint :)

Comment: This article worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/967046/display-brightness-control-not-working-in-17-10

Comment: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT should be only 1 variable and In your post it is "splashacpi_backlight" But "splash and acpi are different parameter it should have space inbetween".

Comment: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=Linux"

Comment: Then update your grub by sudo update-grub

Comment: Sorry @Aravind but that it doesn't solve the problem :(

Comment: I'm building a summary Answer here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045624/how-to-switch-between-options-in-sys-class-backlight-to-solve-brightness-prob You might want to review it for solutions you haven't tried yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a temporally bash script to **adjust brightness level**. Then I create 2 sortcuts at keyboard mapping settings to set up <kbd>CTRL</kbd>  + <kbd>Brightness UP</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Brightness Down</kbd> with this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Step brightness value
STEP=2
# Max brightness value (defult 100)
MAX=100
# Min brightness value (defult 0)
MIN=0

COMMAND=$(xrandr --verbose | grep -i brightness | cut -f2 -d':' | tr -d "[:space:]")
ACTUAL=$(bc -l <<< $COMMAND*100 | cut -f1 -d'.')

while getopts ": u d" input
do
    case $input in
    u)  if [ $ACTUAL -lt $MAX ];then
                TOTAL=$(bc -l <<< $(($ACTUAL+$STEP))/100)
                $(xrandr --output DP-0 --brightness $TOTAL)
        fi;;
    d)  if [ $ACTUAL -gt $MIN ];then
                TOTAL=$(bc -l <<< $(($ACTUAL-$STEP))/100)
                $(xrandr --output DP-0 --brightness $TOTAL)
        fi;;
    ?)  printf "Usage: brightness [OPTION]\n"
        printf "Increase or decrease birghtness on Ubuntu Xorg.\n" 
        printf "WAYLAND MUST BE DISABLED\n\n"
        printf "  -u\t Increases brightness\n"
        printf "  -d\t Decreases brightness\n"
        exit 2;;
    esac
done
```

And in set custom shortcut I added this
[image: Set Custom Shortcut]

Comment: Just noticed this answer and upvoted. Good job.

Comment: Can you please tell where to save this file and how to use it?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like Linux might recognize your backlight. Do you see a `brightness` file in `/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/`? If you do, try writing a number into it and see if it affects the brightness of your screen. You might need to do so as root.

On my system, the Fn+Brightness keys aren't even recognized by Linux in that they don't generate any scancodes, but I can still vary the brightness of my display by giving all users access to the `brightness` file with `chmod` and writing integers into it.

Comment: Hi @dsstorefile. Yes, there are a _brightness_ file in /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/ and I can change the number (as a root) but it doesn't work. Brightness still 100%  :(  My Fn+Brightnes keys generates scancodes :(

Answer (score 3):

## NVIDIA doesn't work with Wayland

As others have discovered, nVidia doesn't play well with Wayland: [Ubuntu 17.10 on Wayland - (How) can I install the NVIDIA drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967955/ubuntu-17-10-on-wayland-how-can-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers). The solution is to switch to Xorg. To summarize the answer from **cl-net** use these steps:

- To install the NVIDIA drivers, execute `sudo apt install nvidia-384`.
- Additionally you can force the GDM login screen to use Xorg by default.
  To achieve this, just execute `sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`.
  Remove the character `#` from the line `# WaylandEnable=false`.
  Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>Y</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save that change.
- Restart the Ubuntu operating system, execute `sudo reboot`.

---

Another problem you will likely encounter is no sound over HDMI to external monitor. To solve this problem see this Q&A: [No Audio Over HDMI on NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008599/no-audio-over-hdmi-on-nvidia-geforce-gtx-1050-ti)

Comment: @albertoiNET when you logged in with Xorg what was your GRUB line for `acpi_backlight=` set to?

Comment: Thanks @WinEunuuchs2Unix . I logged session with "Ubuntu on Xorg" but the problem persiste. Then I installed and used nvidia-384 drivers, but I'm in the same situation :(  UPDATE outputs with new values

Comment: No, my grub line doesn't have any option. This is my line: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

Comment: @albertoiNET Now that you are running Xorg instead of Wayland this Q&A provides additional things to try: https://askubuntu.com/questions/935585/nvidia-backlight-brightness-problem

Comment: Thanks @WinEunuuchs2Unix . I use Ubuntu on Xorg and install NVIDIA drivers. It's meaning disable Wayland. But can't change brightness. xrandr works.

Comment: @albertoiNET Wayland was only default for 17.10. In 18.04 xorg will be default again. What does `cat /sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness` reveal? Also is error gone when you do: `journalctl -b | grep -i nvidia`?

Comment: Hi @WinEunuuchs2Unix. Ubuntu 18.04 isn't launched yet until 26th April. I'm wrong? This commandreveal a integer, but when I tray to change brightness doesn't change. Journalctl shows this output : https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/GmtkNcmCh6/

Comment: Don't install 18.04 as soon as it comes out. I was only pointing out how Wayland seems more like an experiment and not ready for primetime.

Comment: I try to wait to 18.04 Ubuntu. Meanwhile I will use Ubuntu on Xorg with Nvidia-390 drivers

Comment: @albertoiNET Don't install 18.04 the first day it comes out. Come back here and read bug reports for a few weeks to make sure you won't be affected with "new release blues".

Answer (score 0):

While we're at it let's make a large list of other options that "people have tried" out there (this is a community wiki, feel free to add some of your own!)

Update to kernel 4.18

Update to Ubuntu 19.04 (or non gnome at least) https://askubuntu.com/a/1152763/20972

video.only_lcd option https://askubuntu.com/a/1041595/20972

try switching to mainline kernel https://askubuntu.com/a/1030296/20972 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1775065

acpi_osi= (i.e. blank) https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1775065

switch to nouveau on 19.04

If xbacklight works then setup some keyboard shortcuts to call it. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/440843/8337

NVreg_EnableBacklightHandler https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1025559/linux/solus-nvidia-gtx-1070-brightness-control-not-working/

use_native_backlight option https://askubuntu.com/a/937133/20972