# Brightness not working on ubuntu 17.10, broken upgrade from 17.04?

Tags: boot, grub2, 17.10, brightness, backlight

There are multiple similar questions present, but none addressed my concern. I recently upgraded from 17.04 to 17.10.

Full story:

1. I start the system:
   Dell logo -> a dark maroon screen -> Display is completely off -> The login screen sound. If I could see anything now, I would type my password and login.
2. I turn off the system.
3. Power on again. Select recovery mode from the grub options and start. Ubuntu starts up and everything's good after the login, but now I cannot change the brightness of the screen. It's set to maximum.

Things I tried without any success:

1. changing the contents of /etc/default/grub as mentioned here: [Display brightness control not working in 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967046/display-brightness-control-not-working-in-17-10)
2. Using `xbacklight`
3. Running `ls /sys/class/backlight/` doesn't return me any module. Related bug report:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/1724933
4. Cannot find the UI for changing the brightness anywhere
5. Shortcut keys for brightness is not working

Does brightness not work in the recovery mode?
If it's so, can anyone please give any clues on why I am unable to login to Ubuntu 17.10 in the normal mode?

I also created a live USB  of 16.04 to reset everything. After selecting the USB while starting up the system, it takes me nowhere. Stucks at a black blank screen for hours.

Comment: Just a comment... You could always try 16.04 which has a long track record and supported for a couple more years. 17.04 is no longer supported and 17.10 will have support dropped soon.

Comment: Cannot do that either. Live USB has refused to work on my system. I guess I'll have to visit a service center. Seems a hardware issue now.

Comment: You can search Ubuntu for Live USB's not booting or post a new question if none match your make/model/problem. If Live USB isn't working how did you install Ubuntu in the first place?

Comment: It worked when I first installed 16.04. It doesn't work now. My friend has an identical system with 16.04. I could login to his system using the same live USB.  Anyways, I'm pretty sure there's some display driver issue. Will research in deep when I'll have some free time.